# Filter an array based on empty value in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, swift, filter

I am trying to filter an array of dictionaries. The below code is the sample of the scenario i am looking for

```
let names = [ 
    [ "firstName":"Chris","middleName":"Alex"],
    ["firstName":"Matt","middleName":""],
    ["firstName":"John","middleName":"Luke"],
    ["firstName":"Mary","middleName":"John"],
]
```

The final result should be an array for whom there is a middle name.

Answer (score 6):

This did the trick

```
names.filter {
  if let middleName = $0["middleName"] {
    return !middleName.isEmpty
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the nil-coalescing operator to express this quite succinctly:

```
let noMiddleName = names.filter { !($0["middleName"] ?? "").isEmpty }
```

This replaces absent middle names with empty strings, so you can handle either using `.isEmpty` (and then negate if you want to fetch those *with* middle names).

You can also use optional chaining and the nil-coalescing operator to express it another way:

```
let noMiddleName = names.filter { !($0["middleName"]?.isEmpty ?? true) }
```

`$0["middleName"]?.isEmpty` will call `isEmpty` if the value isn’t `nil`, but returns an optional (because it might have been `nil`).  You then use `??` to substitute `true` for `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly shorter:

```
let result = names.filter { $0["middleName"]?.isEmpty == false }
```

This handles all three possible cases:

- If the middle name exists and is *not* an empty string, then
  `$0["middleName"]?.isEmpty` evaluates to `false` and the predicate
  returns `true`.
- If the middle name exists and *is*  empty string, then
  `$0["middleName"]?.isEmpty` evaluates to `true` and the predicate
  returns `false`.
- If the middle name does *not exist*, then
  `$0["middleName"]?.isEmpty` evaluates to `nil` and the predicate
  returns `false` (because `nil` != `false`).

Answer (score 1):

This also works fine

```
names.filter {

if let middleName = $0["middleName"] {
 return middleName != ""
}
return false
}
```

Comment: the others are more succinct, but this is more readable for those not familiar with closure syntax